# Google Keep: searching within a given tag

Tags: accessibility, google-keep

I was wondering whether there is a way to search within a given tag in Google Keep.

On Stack Exchange it is possible to do so, so I was wondering how to do this in Keep.

This can or could be particularly useful when you've got many entries within keep, and even selecting any given tag presents a long list.

It would be nice if this feature were available.

Thanks.